# Simple click handling of many SVG paths works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dom-events

I'm working on an interactive fine-grained US map with about ~35K polygons in d3. I came across this problem once I started wanting to respond to clicks on the individual polygons. I'm using SVG path elements to render the polygons.

**The problem is I can't get Chrome to respond to click events on the SVG in what I would call interactive rates (~sub-second response times) while Firefox handles the scenario with no problem. Hopefully there is some voodoo I'm missing or perhaps something simple I've overlooked?**

[image]

I simplified the problem below to pure JavaScript with just the essentials. I generate a bunch of square cells using SVG path elements (to simulate my map) and then attach click handlers. Try the different versions of *numberOfPathCellsPerSide* and mouse click the SVG map to see progressive performance degradation in Chrome vs. the instant performance in Firefox.

[Working JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcLxcsnm/)

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// numberOfPathCellsPerSide * numberOfPathCellsPerSide = total number of SVG path "polygons".
// Click handler response time seems to be tied to total number of paths rather than the
// size of each path. Also, as you will see down below, several different variations
// of click event listening were tried to no avail.
// Try uncommenting each in succession to experience the performance variations
// between Chrome and Firefox:
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var numberOfPathCellsPerSide = 100; // 100 x 100 = 10,000 total paths => ~instant in Chrome, ~instant in Firefox
//var numberOfPathCellsPerSide = 200; // 200 x 200 = 40,000 total paths => ~7 sec in Chrome, ~instant in Firefox
//var numberOfPathCellsPerSide = 300; // 300 x 300 = 90,000 total paths => ~48 sec in Chrome, ~instant in Firefox

var lengthOfPathCell = 5;

var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var description = document.createElement("div");
description.innerHTML =
        "Total number of svg paths: " + numberOfPathCellsPerSide * numberOfPathCellsPerSide + "<br><br>";
document.body.appendChild(description);

var lengthOfSVGContainer = numberOfPathCellsPerSide * lengthOfPathCell;


var svg = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "svg");
document.body.appendChild(svg);

svg.setAttributeNS (null, "width", lengthOfSVGContainer);
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "height", lengthOfSVGContainer);

var g = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "g");
svg.appendChild(g);

for(var i=0; i<(numberOfPathCellsPerSide * numberOfPathCellsPerSide); i++)
{
    var path = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "path");

    var x = (i % numberOfPathCellsPerSide) * lengthOfPathCell

    var y = Math.floor(i / numberOfPathCellsPerSide) * lengthOfPathCell;

    var drawCellCommands =
            "M " + x + " "  + y + " " +
            "L " + (x + lengthOfPathCell) + " "  + y + " " +
            "L " + (x + lengthOfPathCell) + " "  + (y + lengthOfPathCell) + " " +
            "L " + x + " "  + (y + lengthOfPathCell) + " " +
            "L " + x + " "  + y + " ";

    path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", drawCellCommands);
    path.style.fill = "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)";

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Several different variants of listening for click events.
    // Leave one of them uncommented to see it doesn't seem to matter!
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // listener attempt 1: create an anonymous handler function for each path cell
    path.addEventListener("click", function(e)
    {
        console.log("finally handled the click...");
        alert("finally handled the click...");
    });

    // listener attempt 2: use the same named handler function for each path cell
    //path.addEventListener("click", namedClickHandler);

    g.appendChild(path);
}

// listener attempt 3: leverage delegation by using a single named handler once on enclosing SVG parent element
// Should be the most responsive yet still seems to make no difference in Chrome
//svg.addEventListener("click", namedClickHandler);

function namedClickHandler(e)
{
    console.log("finally handled the click...");
    alert("finally handled the click...");
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but profiling a click shows that 99.99% of the time is spent in "(program)," which suggests it might be a problem with Chrome itself and not JavaScript related.

Comment: Yes, I suspect Chrome has implemented some kind of brute force hit test to figure out the clicked target and maybe Firefox used something smarter like an R-tree.

Comment: UPDATE: seems to be fixed in Chrome as of version 51.0.2704.103 m